# core plot error?

Tags: iphone

i am using core plot framework,when i run following code in viewdidload  gives crash.the view is as custom view...

```
graph = [(CPXYGraph *)[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CPLayerHostingView *hostingView = (CPLayerHostingView *)self.view;
hostingView.hostedLayer = graph;**(gives error)**
```

what i have to do? any help please?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is `self.view` a CPLayerHostingView or some other kind of UIView?

Comment: self.view is normal UIView.

Comment: Why cannot I downvote comments, here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just cast `self.view` to a CPLayerHostingView. You need to make sure it is actually  is one. You can do that in Interface Builder or in code if you're initializing your view that way.